# How to automatically trim string when persisting a Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I have this entity:

```php
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private ?string $name = null;

    // getter setters ...
}
```

My controller:

```php
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $myEntity = new MyEntity();
        $myEntity->setName('  awesome name  ');
        $em->persist($myEntity);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

I want doctrine to register the `name` of `myEntity` as `awesome name` and not  `awesome name` .

Is there a way to configure doctrine to do this?

Comment: Alexandre, saw the answer below?

Comment: @yivi I saw it but it's not what I'm looking for, because when you create your entity with Serializer Component this "trick" doesn't work, because you don't use the `setter`, I should have mention this in my question.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that Symfony Serializer does use the setter, not reflection. Pretty sure of it. This is not a "trick" but simply using the language.

Comment: I wanted to try it out, but I will be able to do so in 7hours, that why I didn't accept your answer yet

Comment: And I was also aware of this trick. But I wanted a more "global" way to do it.

Comment: Again, not a "trick", but the proper way of doing it. There is no ready made "global" way of doing it. You could build a preFlush listener and trim there... but it would be more work, more trouble, and less transparent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237576/discussion-between-alexandre97122-and-yivi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to "configure doctrine" in any way. Just use PHP and introduce the logic in your entity:

```
class MyEntity {
    // ... rest of the class implementation

    public function setName(?string $name): void {
        $this->name = $name === null ? $name : trim($name);
    }
}
```

This way your data will be in a consistent state **before** you persist it in the database.